# Spring data query to neo4j query

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am beginner on Neo4j , I want to convert Spring data query to Neo4j Query.

I have three tables.

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "IS_ATTENDING_EVENT")
public class IsAttendingEventDO {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Property
    private String isAttendingEventId;
    @StartNode
    private PersonDO personDO = new PersonDO();
    @EndNode
    private EventDO eventDO = new EventDO();


@NodeEntity(label="Person")
public class PersonDO {  

    @GraphId Long id;
    @Property
    private String personId;
    @Property
    private String name; 


@NodeEntity(label="Event")
public class EventDO {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Property
    private String eventId;
```

Here is my spring-data query.

```
IsAttendingEventDO getByEventEventIdAndPersonPersonId(String eventId, String personId);
```

Please help me to convert this query to Neo4j query.

Regards,
Parth Solanki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read through the [Neo4j developers manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/) and get an understanding of Cypher syntax and usage.

With basic understanding of Cypher, it's a very simple query. Just match on the pattern you are interested in (a person attending an event, using the labels already defined), provide variables on the person, the event, and the relationship, add a WHERE clause to restrict the person and the event in the match to the given id parameters, then return the relationship that fits the matched pattern where those predicates apply:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[rel:IS_ATTENDING_EVENT]->(e:Event)
WHERE p.id = {personId} AND e.id = {eventId}
RETURN rel
```

EDIT:

Answering your comment about returning the list of relationships (of a :Person attending an :Event) where the only given parameter is the eventId.

To form lists from nodes, you can use the COLLECT() function.

So if you're trying to get the relationships based only on an eventId, you don't need to supply a variable on the :Person node, as you don't have any predicate to apply to it, and you aren't using it or returning it. All you're interested in are relationships of people attending the event with the given eventId, and returning the collection of those returned relationships.

```
MATCH (:Person)-[rel:IS_ATTENDING_EVENT]->(e:Event)
WHERE e.id = {eventId}
RETURN COLLECT(rel)
```

Again, please read through the developers manual, and also use the [Cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) to help you out. The kind of questions you're asking are very easily done when you have read through the basic documentation.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer . I will try this and let you know...and also i have one another query List<IsAttendingEventDO> findByEventEventId(String eventId); so in this it return a list , so how can i make this query ?

Comment: Answered. Please read through the documentation when you get the chance, that should help you out with most other questions you may have about transforming your Spring data query to Cypher; although there is not an explicit conversion guide, it should become intuitive, based upon the pattern you are seeking and the parameters available to you.